# Convert a key-value representing string to a list

Tags: groovy

I have a string say something like

```
'Content-Type: application/json' \
'Postman-Token: a47537e5-b4b0-4915-93c8-92acf4b21e70' \
'cache-control: no-cache' \
```

I want it in a format like

```
['Content-Type' : 'application/json','Postman-Token' : 'a47537e5-b4b0-4915-93c8-92acf4b21e70','cache-control' : 'no-cache']
```

Comment: Please add what you have tried and how that fails.

Comment: At first glance it looks like you want to split at `\`, remove the `'` quotes, split at first `:` then put that into a map?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code for you:

```
def tokens = 'Content-Type: application/json Postman-Token: a47537e5-b4b0-4915-93c8-92acf4b21e70 cache-control: no-cache'.minus(":").replaceAll(":", "") .split(" ")
def map2 = [ : ]
def i = 0
0.step(tokens.length, 2) {
    map2.put(tokens[i], tokens[i+1])
    i = i + 2
}

println JsonOutput.toJson(map2)
```

The result:

```
 {"Content-Type":"application/json","Postman-Token":"a47537e5-b4b0-4915-93c8-92acf4b21e70","cache-control":"no-cache"}
```